# find -ctime -1 finds all my files, not only the recently changed ones

Tags: linux, bash, find, ctime, clamav

I need to check a directory and subfolders every hour, but only for new files.

So i wrote a script with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /var/www/html/files/ -ctime -1 |
clamscan -r --remove --log=/var/log/clam/clamscan.log
```

But for a reason, it doesn't check only the new files, it checks every file (about 6000).

The funny thing is, when I'm for example in the /tmp/ folder and I run `find -ctime -1 | clamscan`
it works.

So I guess I'm missing something but I can't think of what it is.

Comment: Then something else is updating the change time of those 6,000 files?

Comment: no, nothing is updating the files. the timestamp also is older than 1day. some are years old.

Comment: Does the file system support ctime, or only mtime?

Comment: @tripleee yes it does support ctime, for example when i just hit "find -ctime -1" it gives me the correct output

Comment: But `/var/www/html/files` can be on a separate filesystem with different flags and/or capabilities

Comment: @tripleee i just tried "find -ctime -1" in the directory and he shows me all files.... not just the the new ones. but i get the same output with "find -mtime +1"

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `/tmp` supports ctime but `/var/www/html/files` is apparently on a different file system which doesn't.

Lack of ctime support is relatively common for various reasons; probably try with `-mtime` instead, or refactor to keep track of which files existed in the previous iteration (or perhaps switch to `inotify` or similar) if you really absolutely have to watch for new files.

Comment: Maybe you´re right. 
Unfortunately im not familiar with inotify, so i solved it this way: 
I let the webpage move the files which are older than 1 day to another folder. 
So i dont need the mtime/ctime for the clamscan.